# image looks miniscule on bigger screen (Nexus 7), but fills whole screen in smaller screens (Nexus 4)

Tags: android, imageview

Is there a way to set imageview size as a proportion of display size?
I have an image that should roughly take half the screen size but I am not able to set the dimensions properly. it looks ok in smaller screens (like Nexus 4) but looks tiny in bigger screens (Nexus 7). Can we do it through xml?
Or, will I have to store different image sizes for the same image in drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi etc.?? I have close to 50 images. Storing multiple copies is going to increase my app size a lot :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set imageview size as a proportion of display size?

Use `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/fifty_percent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="@string/thirty_percent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:text="@string/twenty_percent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Containers/LinearPercent))

Or, use `PercentFrameLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF00FFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="30%"/>

  <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFF00FF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="40%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="20%"/>

  <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/end"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="65%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="30%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Or, use `PercentRelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#FF00FFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="30%"/>

  <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/start"
    android:background="#FFFF00FF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="20%"/>

  <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/end"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/center"
    android:background="#FFFFFF00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="30%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

(those latter two are from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Percent/Comparison))

> will I have to store different image sizes for the same image in drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi etc.?

Screen *density* (hdpi, mdpi, etc.) is unrelated to screen *size*.

Comment: thanks! foolish of me to relate screen size to screen density.. I am trying to use PercentRelativeLayout and I am getting the error Error:(7) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_widthPercent' in package com.myPackage.myClass